# ¿Que agregar y donde para que funcione correctamente el EventListener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy creando un proyecto de un curso, les paso captura del proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el lado izquierdo hay un boton **Nuevo proyecto**, al darle click se crean inputs y al dar enter, el texto de los inputs se agrega a la lista debajo de **Proyectos**.

Quisiera que al apretar **Nuevo Proyecto**, solo se cree un input y no varios, porque si se abren varios como en la imagen. En la imagen, seria el ejemplo, se abrieron 4 inputs y al primero le escribi **Esto se va repetir 4**, se van agregar 4 elementos a la lista valiendo **Esto se va repetir 4**.

Y quisiera que luego de que el input se agregue a la lista, recien ahi, al tocar en **Nuevo Proyecto** se cree otro input

Ahora les paso el código del sidebar.php

```
<aside class="contenedor-proyectos">
    <div class="panel crear-proyecto">
        <a href="#" class="boton">Nuevo Proyecto <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> </a>
    </div>

    <div class="panel lista-proyectos">
            <h2>Proyectos</h2>
        <ul id="proyectos">
                <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Diseño Página Web
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Nuevo Sitio en wordPress
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Y ahora el código del scripts.js

```
eventListeners();

//lista de proyectos
var listaProyectos = document.querySelector('ul#proyectos');


function eventListeners(){
    //boton para crear proyecto
    document.querySelector('.crear-proyecto a').addEventListener('click', nuevoProyecto);
};

function nuevoProyecto(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Presionaste en nuevo proyecto');

    // crea input para nombre del new proyecto
    var nuevoProyecto = document.createElement('li');
    nuevoProyecto.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="nuevo-proyecto"></input>';
    listaProyectos.appendChild(nuevoProyecto);

    //selecionar id con el nuevo proyecto
    var inputNuevoProyecto = document.querySelector('#nuevo-proyecto');

    // al presionar enter creal el proyecto

    inputNuevoProyecto.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
        var tecla = e.which || e.keycode;

        if(tecla === 13) {
            guardarProyectoBD(inputNuevoProyecto.value);
            listaProyectos.removeChild(nuevoProyecto);
        };
    });
};

function guardarProyectoBD(nombreProyecto){
    // inyectar html
    var nuevoProyecto = document.createElement('li');
    nuevoProyecto.innerHTML = `
        <a href="#">
            ${nombreProyecto}
        </a>
    `;
    listaProyectos.appendChild(nuevoProyecto);

};
```

Lo que intenté, fue agregarle:

```
Once:true
```

al eventListener, quedando asi:

```
document.querySelector('.crear-proyecto a').addEventListener('click', nuevoProyecto,{once:true});
```

Pero eso no es una solución del todo efectiva, ya que después de agregar un elemento, al tocar el botón no se crea un nuevo input.

Comment: Para evitar que existan mas de un input type="text" como el caso que muestras en tu foto, puedes antes de crear el nuevo li junto con el input preguntar si listaProyectos.querySelectorAll('li > input[type="text"]').length > 0, con eso solo insertaras si ya no existe uno previamente creado (A todo esto en el método `nuevoProyecto`

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas Es decir, el if seria desde antes de var nuevoProyecto..... hasta despues de de listaProyectos.appendChild? Si es asi, lo intenté pero no funciona

Comment: Ponme lo que intentastes si no es demasiado asi podre guiarte mejor!

Comment: Si, perdón por no decirlo antes.
Coloqué el if con la condición que me mencionaste y desde antes de donde creo el elemento li, es decir antes de **var nuevoProyecto = document.createElement('li');** hasta despues que termina el addEventListener. Antes del cierre de llave la funcion nuevoPoryecto.

Comment: el problema es que no estas tomando en cuenta el ciclo de vida de los eventos. https://www.genbeta.com/desarrollo/dom-event-capturing-vs-bubbling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dicen en los comentarios, una posibilidad es contar los inputs preexistentes y, dependiendo de esto realizar la acción o no. Otra manera puede ser simplemente agregando un flag, que sea true o false dependiendo de si queremos o no agregar inputs.

Pero en mi opinión, lo mas amigable para el usuario sería o bien que el botón mismo no aparezca cuando no es posible agregar otro proyecto o que aparezca disabled. Aqui te dejo un ejemplo que oculta el botón:

```js
eventListeners();

//lista de proyectos
var listaProyectos = document.querySelector('ul#proyectos');


function eventListeners() {
  //boton para crear proyecto
  document.querySelector('.crear-proyecto a').addEventListener('click', nuevoProyecto);
};

function nuevoProyecto(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.style.display = 'none';
  console.log('Presionaste en nuevo proyecto');

  // crea input para nombre del new proyecto
  var nuevoProyecto = document.createElement('li');
  nuevoProyecto.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="nuevo-proyecto"></input>';
  listaProyectos.appendChild(nuevoProyecto);

  //selecionar id con el nuevo proyecto
  var inputNuevoProyecto = document.querySelector('#nuevo-proyecto');

  // al presionar enter creal el proyecto

  inputNuevoProyecto.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    var tecla = event.which || event.keycode;

    if (tecla === 13) {
      listaProyectos.removeChild(nuevoProyecto);
      e.target.style.display = 'block';
      console.log("proyecto guardado")
    };
  });
};
```

```html
<aside class="contenedor-proyectos">
  <div class="panel crear-proyecto">
    <a href="#" class="boton">Nuevo Proyecto <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> </a>
  </div>

  <div class="panel lista-proyectos">
    <h2>Proyectos</h2>
    <ul id="proyectos">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
                    Diseño Página Web
                </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
                    Nuevo Sitio en wordPress
                </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Funciona a la perfección!

Answer (score 1):

el problema que tienes es con el ciclo de vida de los eventos Capturing, Bubbling seria bueno que investigues acerca de ello.

Sin embargo para salir del apuro puedes solucionarlo verificando el origen del evento de la siguiente manera:

```
if (tecla === 13 && event.target === document.querySelector('#nuevo-proyecto')) {
      listaProyectos.removeChild(nuevoProyecto);
      e.target.style.display = 'block';
      console.log("proyecto guardado")
};
```

Comment: Tengo muy poca experiencia en lo que es JavaScript.Gracias por el aporte, consejo y por el link de los comentarios, estoy viendo esa página y tiene muchas cosas útiles!